# Aggregation Mongodb 3.4

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection wit documents like this. And I want to change value inside subdocument

```
{ "cities" :[
        {
            "city" : "London", 
            "country" : "United Kingdom"
        }, 
        {
            "city" : "New York", 
            "country" : "United States"
        }
        {
            "city" : "San Francisco", 
            "country" : "United States"
        }]
}
```

If city is `San Francisco` then Sf
If city is `New york` then NY
Else `null`

I used `$switch` but does not work. I am using MongoDB `v3.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      cities: {
        $map: {
          input: "$cities",
          in: {
            country: "$$this.country",
            city: {
              $switch: {
                branches: [
                  {
                    case: {
                      $eq: [ "$$this.city","San Francisco"]
                    },
                    then: "Sf"
                  },
                  {
                    case: {
                      $eq: [ "$$this.city", "New York" ]
                    },
                    then: "NY"
                  }
                ],
                default: null
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //Uncomment this stage if aggregation result meets your requirements
  //,{$out: "collection"}
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8jMmGfUP5Lb)